# Изменение свойств списка Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, списки

Проблема в рендере списков, vue не отображает изменения свойств списка, только изменения в структуре самого списка.
При нажатии кнопки change должен изменятся первый элемент списка, но это происходит лишь при изменении структуры списка, то бишь при нажатии кнопки add.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in arr">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button @click="change">change</button>
        <button @click="add">add</button>
        <button @click="restore">restore</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            arr:[1,2,3]
        },
        methods:{
            change:function(){
                this.arr[0] = 'changed';
            },
            add:function(){
                this.arr.push('added');
            },
            restore(){
                this.arr = [1,2,3];
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких случаях помогает [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set):

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data(){
      return {
        arr: [[1,2,3]]
      };
    },
    methods:{
        change(){
            Vue.set(this.arr[0], 0, 'changed');
        },
        add(){
            this.arr.push('added');
        },
        restore(){
            this.arr = [1,2,3];
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul v-for="item in arr">
            <li v-for="subitem in item">{{subitem}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button @click="change">change</button>
        <button @click="add">add</button>
        <button @click="restore">restore</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: А как быть с двумерным массивом?

Comment: @AndrewProts обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

В документации [прямо](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) [говорится](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), что такие изменения (в т.ч. установка по индексу, изменение длины массива) не могут быть отслежены из-за особенностей JS, поэтому нужно использовать вышеописанный Vue.set, .$set или (лучше) .splice.